# Are there any more interesting proofs from Principia like the Feynman's lost lecture?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, history

Can calculations following Newton's technique (without fixing axis) but free from the archaic language, be found online?

Answer (score 1):

No such resource exists, to my knowledge.

Newton's presentation in the Principia was a work of brilliance, but as someone put it poetically "Newton's instrument was so difficult to use that only he could wield it with proficiency" (or words to that effect)

My understanding is that all the results obtained in the Principia were later re-obtained using differential calculus.

Comment: There are a few books translating principia into a more readable language, but they rely on analysis too often, there is that book on Feynmans lost lecture, i saw a brachistochrone proof, but that's about it that I could find.